# SQL Server: Auto increment decimal column

Tags: sql, sql-server, auto-increment

I need to auto increment a decimal column in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: First off... Why? Second, How many DP? Please provide sample data.

Comment: Tried, got this error message: `Identity column 'D' must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, or decimal or numeric with a scale of 0, and constrained to be nonnullable.`

Comment: @JohnHC I have to give a version number where it generates automatically. Example: 1.0, 2.0, . . .

Comment: @ZoharPeled I too got the same error. I think we don't have such option yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My actual requirement is to generate a version number for each call of my stored procedure. I have implemented this as below.

Did creation and updation of table externally

`create table version(no decimal(2,2))
insert into version(1.0)`

Below is the small extract of my stored procedure

`Update version set no=(select max(no) from version)+1`

`select no.version,t.* 
from table t 
left join version`

Answer (score 1):

You should tell us what you want to achieve, but one way to emulate an auto-incremented decimal column is to define it as computed and connected to an auto-incremented normal (integer) column. E.g.:

**Definition:**

```
create table AutoincrementDecimalTest
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    SomeText NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    -- you may declare it as persisted, if the extra space is not problem
    AutoincrementDec AS CAST(Id * 0.2 AS NUMERIC(18, 2))
)
```

Of course, some limitations apply for what your expression, as pointed out [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300(v=sql.120).aspx#Limitations).

**Testing:**

```
insert into AutoincrementDecimalTest (SomeText) VALUES ('test1'), ('test2')
GO

select * from AutoincrementDecimalTest
GO
```

Comment: Thank you. My actual requirement is to generate a version number for each iteration of my logic. I did achieve this as below. 
Initiated a decimal variable with 1.0 

`Declare @var Decimal(5,2)
Set @var=1.0 `

and then with in the loop of my logic I have set it to @Var+1.
`
Set @var= @var+1
print @var `

Comment: Your solution might work, but you should think in set based terms - multiple inserts at once with auto generation may be much faster then single inserts in a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Declaration in `decimal`, but you get in select integer format only.

```
CREATE TABLE #Record(id decimal(18,0) identity primary key , name VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #Record( name )SELECT 'name1' UNION ALL SELECT 'name2' SELECT * FROM #Record
```